# Как настроить пагинацию в Power bi через Api

Tags: пагинация, powerbi

У меня есть таблица которую я получаю через API, ее лимит 100 записей.Мне нужно получить следующие записи за определенный период. В таблице есть поля more_chats: значение (true/false) и last_ts с определенным числом. Изначальный запрос с параметром since?=0. Запрос работает таким образом, что при передачи в параметр since значение last_ts я получаю следующую порцию данных, пока значение в поле more_chats не станет false. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне настроить функцию??

Спасибо заранее